# How to raw TS packets off a file/url -- Without decoding

Tags: ffmpeg

New to ffmpeg and playing around that to understand better. I'm trying to use ffmpeg code base to get TS packets from a HLS Streaming server. I don't need any decoding as I just have to store the TS packets to be processed later.

First I built a minimal FFMPEG as outlined in https://zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7426. No decoders and only hls and mpegts demuxers. Then using the following code to receive the frames. While inspecting it doesn't seem to be MPEG-TS packets while looking into buffers thru GDB. Attaching the code here..

Two Questions:

1. Shouldn't the av_recv_frame get me the TS packets? However When I trace all the way to playlists (off HLSContext), the read_buffer there contains TS packets. IS there any example I could look into to get TS packets in this scenario without decoders?
2. If I get answer for (1), How to get the best stream off the HLS server? when looking into ffplay, av_find_best_stream() sounds like the one to look into.. But again without needing to decode, is there a way to get best one according to the network condition?

Thanks..

I dumped whatever I got off `av_recv_frame()` and stored in file. This file is not playable with VLC but Windows Movies & TV player could play the sound with missing frames..

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    AVFormatContext * ifmt_ctx = NULL; 
    char *in_filename = NULL; 
    int ret = 0; 
    AVPacket pkt; 
    if (argc != 2) { return 1; } 
    in_filename = argv[1]; 
    av_register_all();

    if (!(ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context())) { goto end; } 
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file '%s'", in_filename); 
        goto end; 
    } 
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to retrieve input stream information"); 
        goto end; 
    }

    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, in_filename, 0); 
    while (1) { 
        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt); 
        if (ret < 0) break; 
        av_free_packet(&pkt); 
    } 
    end: avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx); return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code as markdown in the question body, not in the comments. It will work. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details

Comment: thanks jrswgtr for editing my question to bring the code there..

Comment: Got more info. What gets returned from av_recv_frame is either Audio/Video stream from the HLS server. Also its not given as TS packets. So my question is how to get TS packets as is?

Comment: If you only want raw file data from a server then just simply do an actual HTTP request and store the received bytes as file. When you want media processing then use FFmpeg on stored TS file(s).

Comment: Raw data when I call appropriate segment url is TS packets and I could store directly. But I want to make use of HLS demuxer of ffmpeg to take care of all playlist handling. So after hls_read_header (part of initial open_input), I assume the subsequent hls_read_packet() (from av_recv_frame I'm using in the program above) makes sure the playlist is current. I don't want to lose that functionality..

Comment: As I was debugging code to understand this better, I did one thing with the code pasted above. Looked at the corresponding stream's codecpar and saved Audio and Video packets separately. Audio packet file (AAC)  could 
 be played with VLC (but not ffplay). Video packet file (H264) could be played with ffplay (but not VLC).  This shows I'm getting what I needed but NOT as is with TS headers. How to get as is?. Thanks